# Powershell-else in try/catch

Tags: powershell, error-handling, try-catch

I'm trying to write output when `get-addomain` succeded.

Try/catch writes output only if command fails

```
try {

get-addomain -Identity  d.contoso.com  

}

catch {

Write-Output "failed"

}
```

I tried following:

```
if (-not (get-addomain -Identity  d.contoso.com))
{
return "failed"
}

else

{
write-output "ok"
}
```

and

```
If (get-addomain -Identity  d.contoso.com  )
{
    Write-Output "ok"
}
Else
{
    write-output "failed"
}
```

but in both cases got

```
get-addomain : Cannot find an object with identity: 'd.contoso.com' under: 'DC=ad,DC=contoso,DC=com'.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `try`block runs until a error is getting thrown. If `get-addomain` doesn't end with an error, the try-case will run the following commands written inside the `{}`.

So one way would be to just say the output is ok if no error gets thrown:

```
try {
  get-addomain -Identity  d.contoso.com  
  Write-Output "ok"
}

catch {
  Write-Output "failed"
}
```

But if you want to double check, you can still do the `if` check in the `try-catch`:

```
try {
  If (get-addomain -Identity  d.contoso.com  )
  {
      Write-Output "ok"
  }
  Else
  {
    write-output "failed"
  }
}
catch {
  Write-Output "failed"
}
```

Comment: second solution worked !!, thanks, first one also works if i specify | out-null

Answer (score 0):

```
try{
    $domain = Get-ADDomain -Identity d.contoso.com
    Write-Output $domain
}catch{
    Write-Output "Failed with message '$($_.Exception.Message)'"
}
```

When you use the AD CmdLets, it fails when a non-existing identity is specified. Therefore if the object you search for does not exist, you will end up in the catch. The first piece of code you wrote is actually correct if you wish to output the AD domain information.